# how to print a data of csv file in c?

Tags: c, csv, printf

I tried whis method but its not working any helps?
one more thing: I need to do some searching into the csv file.. to return when a word that search was founded I need to return which row it's showing.
(sorry about the low level of my english)
my code here:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <conio.h>
#define ROW 20
#define LEN 60

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
char  search = 'a';
int choice = 0, counter = 0, row = 0, col = 0, i = 0, j = 0;
FILE *data;
data = fopen(argv[2], "r");
if (data == NULL){
    printf("\n file opening failed ");
    return 1;
}
char c;
while ((c = fgetc(data)) != EOF){
    printf("%s", c);
}
```

Comment: `char c;` --> `int c;` -- `printf("%s", c);` --> `printf("%c", c);`

Comment: Look into [`fgets`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/) and [`strstr`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/).

Comment: *is not working* just means nothing. Please describe what happens...

Comment: its crached in the VS after printnitg some junk value..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it would be better to change the way you're handling your file processing. Use fgets() to read a line from the file.

```
   char buffer[255] = {0};
   data = fopen (argv[2], "r");
   if (data == NULL)
   {
       printf("\n Failed to open file!");
   }
   else {
     while(( fgets( buffer, 255, data )) != NULL)
     {
        puts(buffer);
        /* Some processing */
     }
     fclose (data);
   }
   return 0;
```

Once you've buffered a line from your csv file you can use strtok() to get the particular values from the line.

Answer (score 2):

```
 printf("%s", c);
```

Should be changed to

```
 printf("%c", c);
```

As c is char

Comment: Good to say that `c` must be an `int` instead of a `char` in order to catch `EOF`

Comment: its not working yet..I tried all things.. first I need to print the csv file,can you send code or something?